# how to dynamically update the nested objects in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

We have some arbitrarily nested configuration that we store in the mongodb.

1. Let say we initially store the following object in the mongodb.

```
const value = { 'a': { 'b': 1 } }

collection.insertOne({userId, value})
```

now I want to modify the object in the database by adding

```
const addValue = { 'f': { 'c': 2 } }
```

and similarly with few more nested object.

```
const addValue1 = { 'a': { 'd': 1 }, 'f': { 'g': 1 } };
```

As we adding, these `keys` are very dynacmic and should able to update value in the db but not replace it, so expecting the end result stored should be

```
const result = collection.findOne({ userId });

console.log(result);

{ 'a': { 'b': 1, 'd': 1 }, 'f': { 'g': 1, 'c': 2 } }
```

And also overwrite if the udpate value is

```
const addValue2 = { 'a': { 'b' : { 'e': 1 } } }
```

expected result is

```
const result2 = { 'a': { 'b': { 'e': 1 } , 'd': 1 }, 'f': { 'g': 1, 'c': 2 } }
```

### Similarly when deleting

```
    let testObject = new MongoDBStorageService('test', dbConnection as any, 'userTestSchema');

    testObject.load({ 'a': { 'b': 1 }});
    testObject.removeValue('a.b');

    const content = await testObject.contents;

 expect(content).toEqual({}); // but we see output as `{ a: {} }`
```

Remove method used

```
public async removeValue(key: string) {
        return await this.remove(JSON.parse(`{\"${key}\": "" }`));
    }
private remove(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.collection.updateOne({ user: this.userId }, {
            $unset: value,
        }, { upsert: false }, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('REUSLL AFTER REMOVE', res.);
                resolve({ id: true });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is that you have to convert your objects into MongoDB's dot notation which can be used to build your update statements. You can do that by running below function:

```js
let flatten = (obj, prefix, result) => {
    result = result || {};
    for(let key of Object.keys(obj)){
        let keyExpr = prefix  ? `${prefix}.${key}` : `${key}`;
        if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
            flatten(obj[key], keyExpr, result);
        } else {
            result[keyExpr] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const addValue = { 'f': { 'c': 2 } }
let update1 = flatten(addValue)
console.log(update1);

const addValue1 = { 'a': { 'd': 1 }, 'f': { 'g': 1 } };
let update2 = flatten(addValue1);
console.log(update2);
```

```
const value = { 'a': { 'b': 1 } }
const userId = 1;
db.col.insertOne({userId, ...value})

db.col.update({ userId: userId }, { $set: update1 });
db.col.update({ userId: userId }, { $set: update2 });
```

The reason why you can't run [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) directly on your objects is that it will replace existing `a` nested object instead of merging it.

Comment: make sense let me quickly test it

Comment: @user1595858 how's the testing going :) ?

Comment: went good with adding values. But has a problem with deletion.

Comment: @user1595858 it hasn't been initially mentioned that there's any deletion. I can take a look later :-)

Comment: @user1595858 regarding your deleting example: whenever you're running `updateOne` you don't know what's the state of `a` field. You only unset the key you're aware of which is `a.b` but you don't know if there's `a.c`, `a.d` etc. All you can do is run `$unset` and deal with empty objects somehow later. Alternatively you need to `find` the document first and then run update knowing it's full content - but that's two database roundtrips so it's your decision which way is preferrable.